# How to check whether the code is running in development or Production mode in Program.cs file in ASP.NET CORE 2.1?

Tags: c#

I have a web application which is developed in ASP.NET CORE 2.1. I want the code to behave differently in Development and Production mode. I tried `#if Debug else` code but that will not suit my requirement.

Can anyone suggest me how to find the current mode in C# in Program.cs file?

Comment: Behave differently how? Different logic? Or different settings perhaps?

Answer (score 24):

The `IWebHostEnvironment` interface provides the method `IsDevelopment()`. Simply inject that into whatever class you're trying to use it from.

```
public class MyClass
{    
    public MyClass(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // Run development specific code
        }
    }
}
```

If you *really* need to access it from outside of the DI container/scope then you can theoretically read the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. Take note that this is an implementation detail, and by accessing it that way you're bypassing the framework.

```
var isDevelopment = string.Equals(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"), "development", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```