# Production net6 Api rest returns html when it should return a json

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis

I am having a problem after publishing an application to a server, IIS, net6, Angular. In development, the APIs return a JSON adjusted to the type of response that is included, but after publishing them, they return an HTML in their error varieties. This initially occurs in Authentication, which you do through Microsoft authentication to Azure.

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)]
    public ActionResult<Collection<MenuActive>> ActiveMenu()
    {
        try
        {
            var menu= _menuservice.GetActivemenu();
            return Ok(menu);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //loggear exeptions
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new DetalleRespuesta() { Detalle = "Error Get Active menu", Resultado = EnumResultado.RESULTADO_FALLA });
        }

    }
```

The previous code in development, in case of bad authentication or an authentication error, returns a 401 captured by the catch, which is:

[image]

But when you publish it, it becomes the following HTML response:

[image]

I don't understand the variation of result. I suppose it has to do with the fact that when I authenticate you, I enter another page and there is the error due to bad authentication, and this is the error that returns, a page, and not a status code as expected. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

maybe in Program.cs or similar cs files there is a special setting for
Development or Production mode where certain parameters are set different (e.g. allowing http/https only in development)
(like here: [How to check whether the code is running in development or Production mode in Program.cs file in ASP.NET CORE 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244737/how-to-check-whether-the-code-is-running-in-development-or-production-mode-in-pr))

Comment: It was exactly that, thank you very much. I had an IsDevelopment() setting in the Startup.cs